# Excel Add-in connect to REST API

Tags: c#, excel-addins

I need to write an Excel Add-In that communicates with an existing REST API that I created.  The API allows the user to upload data from the excel spreadsheet to a SQL database.  I am not sure how I accomplish this, so it would be great if I could get some sample code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at these:

[VBA-WEB github page](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web)

[Excel Services REST API MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee556413.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

What kind of Excel Add in do you write? I guess you'll use VSTO instead of plain old VBA or even c++ (xll).

For VBA and c++ it will surely be harder to do (and I do not have any samples for these for you), for vsto please have a look here: [Calling a Web API From a .NET Client in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client). It doesn't matter if you are in Excel or somewhere else, you just have to create an http client, configure that client, make your call and work with the result.